# Finding minimal polynomial of invariant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, invariant-subspace

Let us say I have an operator $T:V\rightarrow$$V$, and have been given its minimal polynomial $p(t)$. Let $g(t)$ be a polynomial. We are given (no need to prove) that $W= image(g(T))$ is a T-invariant subspace. How do I find the minimal polynomial of the restriction of $T$ to $W$, i.e. $T_W)$?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of the restriction will be $p(t)/g(t)$

Comment: In the example I am given, $g(t)$ doesn't divide $p(t)$. What about in this case? Could you elaborate on your answer a little?

Comment: That's strange. It's clear that $p(T|_W)$ is zero; it should follow that the minimal polynomial of $T|_W$ divides $p$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, $g(t)$ is not the minimal polynomial of the restriction, it is any arbitrary polynomial.

Comment: Yeah I got things mixed up

Comment: It should turn out to be $p(t)/\gcd(g(t),p(t))$. If this hasn't been proven by tomorrow, I'll write something up formally.

Comment: Hey if not a formal proof, could you perhaps give me some intuition behind that formula?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $d(t) = \gcd(p(t),g(t))$. By the definition of a minimal polynomial, it suffices to show that $m(t) := p(t)/d(t)$ is such that $q(T|_W) = 0$ if and only if $m(t) \mid q(t)$. The easy part is showing that $m(t) \mid q(t)$ implies that $q(T|_W) = 0$.

For the reverse implication: if $q(T|_W) = 0$, we can say that for every $y \in \operatorname{im}(g(T))$, $q(T)y = 0$.  That is, for every $x \in V$ $q(T)[g(T)x] = 0$. In other words, $q(T)g(T) = 0$.  Thus, $p(t) \mid q(t) g(t)$.

Now, there exist coefficients $a,b$ such that $d(t) = ap(t) + bg(t)$. With that,
$$
p(t) \mid q(t)g(t) \text{ and } p(t) \mid p(t)g(t)\implies\\
p(t) \mid q(t) \cdot (ap(t) + bg(t)) \implies\\
p(t) \mid q(t)d(t).
$$
Since $p(t) \mid q(t)d(t)$, it follows that $m(t) = \frac{p(t)}{d(t)} \mid q(t)$. This ends the proof.

Comment: The original version of my proof was wrong; see my latest edit.